# Getting data from multiple UIPicker components

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

I'm trying to gather the selected data in my Picker Field. I have 3 components. How can I call a specific component? I've been trying `dateData[component][row]` but that only returns the last selected component. Is there a way like `dateData[component:1]` ? (I know that doesn't work). Thanks!

Comment: Hey! if you solve this please add your answer or I can provide one for you.

Answer (score 0):

The UIPickerView has an instance function you would call to retrieve the selected row for the given component:

```
- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

This is how the function call would look like if **pickerView** was the instance name:

```
[pickerView selectedRowInComponent: 0]
```